# How will moving the dbcursor in Python's sqlite module affect for-loops?

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop, sqlite

In Python's [sqlite module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html), it says I can use the cursor as an iterator. From what I understand of cursors, it's easy to get tripped up if you forget to reset the cursor position.

So I'm wondering if the two following bits of code will behave differently?

Example 1:

```
for row in dbcursor.execute("SELECT * FROM tableA"):
    dbcursor.execute("SELECT * FROM tableB")
    # do something
```

Example 2:

```
dbcursor.execute("SELECT * FROM tableA")
for row in dbcursor: 
# After the first iteration, will 'dbcursor' here
# refer to the SELECT statement for tableA above or tableB below?
# since dbcursor never gets reset like it does in Example 1 above
    dbcursor.execute("SELECT * FROM tableB")
    # do something
```

Comment: You should not depend on [`cursor.execute()`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id15) returning anything. "Return values are not defined."

Comment: Not sure that applies here. As far as I understand, the DB-API PEP says that because how the cursor is actually implemented depends on the specific python module. In this case, the docs for sqlite3 module specifically show sample code in the form of Example 1 above, which implies that it's okay to depend on the cursor in the stdlib sqlite module returning consistent values... am I missing something?

Comment: Hrm. There's a hole in the `sqlite3` docs then, since it doesn't say that the method returns anything.